# Experience and levels in Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3e, character-advancement

According to answers to this question some levels require more experience than they did in D&D3.x: [Differences between D&D 3.5 and Pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1/differences-between-dd-3-5-and-pathfinder)

How much experience do different levels require in Pathfinder and have the rules for gaining experience changed from D&D3.x?

Comment: It's been too long since I've played 3.5 to really contrast the rules reliably, but the full [Pathfinder character advancement rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement) are available online.

Comment: I completely missed that, thanks. Now, let me see if the rules for much exprience an encounter is worth can also be found...

Comment: A search for "experience challenge rating" turned it up in the [GameMaster section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering). Also, if you do find the differences you're looking for, please post them back here for future users :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3.5 had a fixed table with protected (non-OGL) hit point tables. Pathfinder was obviously not allowed to copy that, but they simplified the system a bit, while making it harder for lower level characters to close in on higher level characters.

An in-depth explanation can be found in this [article by Jonathan Drain at D20 Source](http://www.d20source.com/2010/06/pathfinders-xp-system):

> The big difference with the Pathfinder/UA experience system is that instead of earning a different amount of XP from a creature depending on your party’s current level, **you gain the same XP amount regardless of party level, but higher level monsters give much more XP, and you need more XP to level up.** The overall effect is that the XP numbers get much higher (millions of XP to reach level 20), but players still level up at the same rate as normal.
>
> The main benefit here is that **DMs can combine monsters in encounters more easily** and calculate XP rewards more easily.
>
> [...]
>
> Another change peculiar to Pathfinder RPG is the choice of three XP rates: slow, medium, and fast. Some groups prefer to level up frequently, while others prefer slower levelling.