# How well does pathfinder mix with 3.5e

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

I'm currently running a pathfinder campaign and I'm wondering how well pathfinder meshes with 3.5e in therms of:

- monsters
- magic items
- prestige classes
- spells
- races

How easily can you use 3.5 material in a pathfinder campaign.

Comment: Can you define "meshes"? Are you talking about bringing in the occasional 3.5 item/class/monster or running a whole 3.5 pre-generated adventure with the Pathfinder rules? Or, are you an experienced 3.5 GM/player who wants to know what changes there are between the systems?

Answer (score 1):

You might like [our 3.5e vs Pathfinder question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1/differences-between-dd-3-5-and-pathfinder) which summarizes some differences in character progression the systems.

The systems are intentionally very close.  Character power is a little bit higher in Pathfinder -- characters get traits, more feats, slightly higher stats, favored class bonuses, and more small bonuses when leveling.

Races in Pathfinder are a little better: most of them get 2 more stat points in Pathfinder than in 3.5.  A few magic items are more expensive in Pathfinder, notably the stat bonus items.  A few spells are nerfed a little bit, for example Glitterdust now allows a new save every round.

Some monsters are basically identical -- for example the [3.5 ogre](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ogre.htm) is almost the same as the [Pathfinder ogre](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/ogre/).  Other monsters are stronger in Pathfinder -- for example the [3.5 bearded devil](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm) is four points of STR, plus some hit points, weaker than the [Pathfinder bearded devil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/devil/bearded/).

As far as prestige classes, a great deal depends on the specific class.  Some prestige classes (in each system) are very good, and others are pretty terrible.  Most will require house-ruling to account for the differences in character progression -- for example most wizard prestige classes in 3.5 gave d4 hit dice, which will seem low to Pathfinder wizards who are used to getting d6 hit dice.